# VBScript in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have seen this type of line many places on the net. Should it be something different?

```
$VBScript = New-Object -ComObject MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
```

This happens under both PSVersion 5.0.10586.117 on Windows 7 and GitCommitId 6.0.0-alpha.10 on Windows 10.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> $VBScript = New-Object -ComObject MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}
failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At line:1 char:13
+ $VBScript = New-Object -ComObject MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in the x86 shell of PowerShell? I am guessing you are in the x64 and the object is not accessible there. That and make sure it is registered?

Comment: Yes, it works in PowerShell x86. Thanks.